# docker-compose build error when using parent dir & dockerfile for build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following structure:

```
.
..
docker/cli/Dockerfile
tests/docker-compose.yml
docker-compose.yml
```

In my `tests/docker-compose.yml` I have the following service defined:

```
services:
  test:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ../docker/cli/Dockerfile
  ...
```

When do a `docker-compose build` I get:

```
Building test
ERROR: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../docker/cli ()
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

After I wrote the question I actually found the problem. When you define a context in docker-compose, the `dockerfile:` bit is relative to that context. So the proper configuration would be:

```
  test:
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: docker/cli/Dockerfile
```

I hope this helps someone...

Comment: on podman: Error: forbidden path for "../", it is outside of the build context "/xx/yyy": escaping context directory error

Comment: this is the best answer in history of answers... maybe ever